# ganon.php: call to undefined function file_get_dom()

Tags: php, ganon

I'm trying to use ganon.php to parse html content like I do with jQuery but I'm having an error saying:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_dom()
```

I followed all the instructions in the library page [here](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/):

I placed the "ganon.php" file in the same folder as my file and then included it by:

```
include 'ganon.php';
```

Comment: try changing `include` to `require`, that will throw an error if it cannot find the `ganon.php` file

Comment: thanks! that was an access permission problem